# Cant store Hash table in session - Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session, hashtable

In my application I want to store a hash table  in session and retrieve later from session.

The code is shown below

```
     Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                   DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["FromDate"]);
                   DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["ToDate"]);
                   ht["StartTime"] = fromDate;
                   ht["EndTime"] = toDate;
                   Session["RuleSearchParameterForArchive"] = ht;
```

While debuggin i can see that hashtable ht hold two values (StartTime and EndTIme) .. But when i retrieving ,that always give null .. code is shown below

```
  Hashtable hts = (Hashtable)Session["RuleParametersForArchive"];
                   DateTime dd = Convert.ToDateTime(hts["EndTime"]);
```

While debugging i can see that hastable hts holds null value. Why i cant retrieve value from session. 
Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashtable is stored with a different key (RuleSearchParameterForArchive) than you use when attempting to retrieve it (RuleParametersForArchive).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Silly thing ..but i wasted a lot of time.I must be more careful while coding :(